# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function PROBLEM

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the number of transaction per value   bend analysis for following for each of trans type per the BRACKTS : 1-100 , 101-200

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'MM-YY') MONTH 
, AGENT_NUMBER 
, COUNT(DISTINCT RECEIVER) NUM_OF_CUST 
, COMMAND_ID 
, BRACKETS 
FROM (
    SELECT TRANSDATE 
    , AGENT_NUMBER 
    , RECEIVER 
    , COMMAND_ID 
    , CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT RECEVIVER) BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN '1-100' , 
      WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT RECEIVER) BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN '101-200' 
      ELSE '0' END BRACKETS 
    FROM TRANSACTION@ABSDB 
    WHERE RESULT_CODE = 'DONE' 
    AND TO_CHAR (TRANSDATE,''MM-YY) = '06-21')
GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE,'MM-YY') 
        , AGENT_NUMBER  , COMMAND_ID , BRACKETS
```

Comment: I don't see how this query generates your error.

Comment: The derived table includes a set function, but has no GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` on the inner sub-query for the `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` (and there was at least one typo, maybe two, see the inline comments):

```sql
SELECT MONTH 
,      AGENT_NUMBER 
,      COUNT(DISTINCT RECEIVER) NUM_OF_CUST 
,      COMMAND_ID 
,      BRACKETS 
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE, 'MM-YY') AS month
  ,      AGENT_NUMBER 
  ,      RECEIVER 
  ,      COMMAND_ID 
  ,      CASE 
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT RECEVIVER) BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN '1-100' ,
         --                      ^ Is this spelt correctly?
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT RECEIVER) BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN '101-200' 
         ELSE '0' END BRACKETS 
  FROM   TRANSACTION@ABSDB 
  WHERE  RESULT_CODE = 'DONE' 
  AND    TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE, 'MM-YY') = '06-21'  -- Also the quotes were wrong here
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRANSDATE, 'MM-YY'),
         , AGENT_NUMBER 
         , RECEIVER 
         , COMMAND_ID 
)
GROUP BY  MONTH
        , AGENT_NUMBER
        , COMMAND_ID
        , BRACKETS;
```

Comment: Dear MT0 , many thanks for your answer.. it's helped a lot

Comment: If the answer resolver your issue then kindly accept it. This helps future questioners have the same or similar issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please  do not leave successfully answered questions in the unanswered queue.